# windows xamp with php 7.0.5 and mongodb driver but classes not found

Tags: php, mongodb, xampp, windows-10

After going trough a lot of googling I just cant seem to get my php mongo-db driver working.

I think i have the latest xamp. php 7.0.5 VC14 and I have the latest mongodb driver i could find and it gets displayed by phpinfo()

[image]

If I use `new MongoClient()`, or `new Mongo()` or even `new Mongodb()` I always get an error.

Can someone please point me to a page that can help or even give a solution. My xamp is installed under `c:\dropbox\programming\xamp`. I dont know if that might be the issue?

Comment: Share you PHP code/workaround

Comment: Embedded phpinf() output, minor language improvements, general formating.

Comment: Please update your post and insert the exact error message.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Class not found error.... Sorry for leaving that out of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classes you try to instantiate belong to the old driver (`mongo`). `mongodb` extension is the new driver and its API is totally different, you can check out [manual on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php)

Comment: Thank you for the link the examples there seams to work

Comment: @PaulGrobbelaar you may consider accepting my response then :)